# Which is the best practice either to save image name or full URL in database

Tags: sql, database, image, path

Which is the better approach for storing image name in database? I have two choices first one is to store just image name e.g. `apple.png` and second choice is to store full image URL e.g. `abc.com/src/apple.png`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check some Intermediate solutions, pros/cons of saving the full or incomplete path here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444442/how-do-i-store-the-location-of-an-image-in-a-database/67593646#67593646

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best practice is not save full path to image like abc.com/src/apple.png but saving specific domain path to image. Ex:

- Users image : /user/{id}/avatar/img.png
- Product image: /product/{id}/1.png

In this case you avoid sticking images to defined server, server path, url etc. For example, you will decide to move all your images to another server, in this case you don't need to change all records in DB.

Comment: I have the same opinion as yours, but why wordpress store full image path in database? Is wordpress developer community not following best practices ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not expert in Wordpress but in general both of this cases can be used, even if you store full path and need to move all your images to another server you can write DB migration SQL like 
update <table> set img = replace(img, 'www.abc.com', 'www.def.com');
But it more useful to skip it.

Comment: I found a great tool for replacing old domain with new domain for wordpress database. https://rudrastyh.com/tools/sql-queries-generator

Comment: Yes, as you can see it is set of same query from comment above:
update <table> set img = replace(img, 'www.abc.com', 'www.def.com')
but for all tables, where wordpress store images. Also please check my another comment about polymorphic associations. Maybe this way is more suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 answers already covered it pretty well. It is indeed best practice to save the directory path instead of saving the entire URL path. Some of the reasons were already covered, such as making it easy to move your folders to another server without having to make any changes whatsoever in your file logic.

What you could do, is also have everything in one directory, refer to that, and then just save the image name. However, I would ***not*** recommend that. The other structure simply makes it way easier to navigate and look through. Good file structure is something you'll thank yourself for later in case you ever have to go through things manually for one reason or another.

With that said, I'd like to add this trick into the mix:

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. This always makes you start from the *root directory* as opposed to having to do tedious things, such as `../../` etc. It looks like a mess.

So in the end as an image path, you'd have something like:

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$row['filePath']; ?>" >
```

`$row['filePath']` being your stored filepath from the database.

Depending on how your file path is saved, you can lose the `/` in the image source link.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to upload all images in public folder of your project , so no need to save `domain name`

If you are storing all images in one directory , then there is no problem storing only imagename in database

you can easily access images like `<img src="/foldername/imagename.jpg" />`

but if in your project there are multiple directory like

1. profile :to save user avatar image ,
2. background : to save background images,

then it is better to  save **image with path** in database like `"/profile/avatar.jpg"`

so you can access image like `<img src="imagepathhere" />`

Comment: Is it good to save image URL with domain name ? e.g. abc.com/src/apple.png. If i change the domain name then images will not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Another common way is to create **image** table with cols

- id
- type (enum or int)
- name (file name)
  Define in your app (better in model) types like

`USER_AVATAR = 1;
 PRODUCT_IMG = 2;`

Define path map foreach image type like:

`$paths = [
  USER_AVATAR => '/var/www/project/web/images/users',
  ...
];`

and use id's from this **image** table in another tables. It is called *polymorphic association*. It is most flexible way to store images.