# Is it better to save upload file into SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [store image in database or in a system file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766048/store-image-in-database-or-in-a-system-file)

I am wondering if it is a better idea to save uploaded file into SQL Server. And if it is convenient to download the file stored in DB. If it works, what type of field should I use to store file? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This has been asked repeatedly here. Please search the site.

Answer (score 3):

MS research have written up a good white paper on this - [To BLOB or not to BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525).

Give it a read and make up your mind.

tl;dr:

If most of the files are under ~150kb, might as well store them in the DB.