# Inserting image into database and retrieving it

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I know storing images in the database has to be a "BLOB" but I cant seem to get it to work.  Here is my current code, please tell me what to add in what sections to get the image function to work:

Register Function:

```
  /**
  * Function to  Register
  **/
public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
    return json;
}
```

DB Handler:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyUsers";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
private static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String uid, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, fname); // FirstName
    values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, lname); // LastName
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(KEY_USERNAME, uname); // UserName
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

}


/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("fname", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("lname", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("uname", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(6));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}






/**
 * Getting user login status
 * return true if rows are there in table
 * */
public int getRowCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    // return row count
    return rowCount;
}


/**
 * Re crate database
 * Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void resetTables(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
    db.close();
}

}
```

Register:

```
/**
 * Defining Process dialog
 **/
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
           fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
           lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

        return json;


    }

 /**
 *  JSON Response node names.
 **/

private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
```

The perfect answer would include what needs to be added to which section.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you considered just saving the actual file in a directory and save the file path in the DB instead?

Comment: Unfortunately I need the image stored on the database so other users can retrieve the image

Comment: convert image into string using Base64 then store string in db.

Comment: would the user need to select the image from the gallery ? or can he take a new photo ? and also do you have to send the picture in the registration parameter ? @SlopTonio

Comment: I already have a function which the user can either select an image from the gallery or take one with the camera.  Yes I need the picture to be sent to the registration parameter

Answer (score 0):

I think you should encode your image with Base64

```
String imageEncoded = encodeTobase64(mBitmap);
```

store it in DB, then decode the string to retrieve your image.

```
Bitmap beforeScaleDown = decodeBase64(imageEncoded);
```

Comment: Can u show me the functions to store the image into the db using the code I have

Comment: Just add another field in DB, such as 'avatar'. Then in your addUser method, pass param String imageEncoded.
then  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("avatar", imageEncoded));

Answer (score 0):

You can store images into database. for this you have to make one column with datatype **BLOB**. then after you can retrieve it from database. for your guidance see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database) example.

But here one of my friend said that it is not good to store images into database. he suggests me to store into sdcard rather than database. see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815626/to-do-or-not-to-do-store-images-in-a-database/815639#815639) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766048/store-image-in-database-or-in-a-system-file/766058#766058) for your convenience.

Comment: Those links do not give any reason, except performance, but [measurements indicate the database is better for typical image sizes](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html).