# Unable to insert image file in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert file in database how can i do it with codeigniter... Please note I don't want to store the path of the image. How can I store the image directly in the database?

**Controller**

```
class UserController extendes CI_Controller{
}
```

**Model**

```
class User extends CI_Model{
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you determined to store the image in the database rather than a the file name?

Comment: See this link may be help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650275/codeigniter-image-uploading-mysql

Comment: I dont want to keep it separate in folder structure so that.is there any way to store file directly in the mysql..

Comment: If really want to store the data image in your database, one way to achieve it is to encode it with something like `base64_encode()`.

Comment: do you have any link for refferance

Answer (score 0):

You can store images in table with LONGBLOB datatype in mysql.
just try this-
http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I guess for a better speed in high range of image records, storing the path or image name in a table is much more effective than storing the image data itself.
you need to store the filename or the file path as a varchar and upload the file using uoload library of codeigniter.. This makes the whole process much simpler..!