# What are the Advantages and Disadvantages of Saving the Uploaded Photos to the Database and to the Disk?

Tags: c#, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

In terms of performance, scalability, etc.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815626/to-do-or-not-to-do-store-images-in-a-database and many more questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't save to the DB. You will regret it.

The file system is the best place for storing binary files. It's built to do it.

I've had my fingers burned before, writing a CMS system that stored files in the DB. The result was:

- Massive increase in traffic between the web server and the database
- Slowdown in database performance
- Massive increase in the size of the database, resulting in a backup headache

Generally speaking, manipulating binary files on the file system is easy. Using DB tools like SSMS, it's a nightmare.