# Image Uploading -- is BLOB the way to go?

Tags: php, mysql, blob, image-uploading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)
>   [To Do or Not to Do: Store Images in a Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815626/to-do-or-not-to-do-store-images-in-a-database)

I'm currently in the process of creating my friend's artist portfolio website. She asked me to create a simple system where she can upload an image and it will be displayed on the site *according to the category it is in*. I've stumbled upon several useful and interesting ways in which to achieve this and I've narrowed it down to the *two* that seem the most useful for me. Unfortunately, I do not know which one would be a better choice.

**Option A**: http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql

> This method uses a very controversial way of storing images in a mySQL
>   table using the `blob` datatype. I've read that it isn't recommended
>   by many PHP programmers, however, it does seem like it can fit my
>   needs perfectly. From what I understand it is fairly simple and easy:
>
> 1. Upload Image to DB
> 2. Display Image from DB according to category chosen.

**Option B:** http://webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=101466

> This method only shows how to upload an image to a directory using
>   PHP. I figured once that is done I could make a simple list of all the
>   images in that directory and put it into an array. Afterwards loop
>   through the array and display those items in `<img>` tags.

So, you see, I am still learning how to work with PHP and mySQL and this website is great motivation to learn. However, I'm unsure
of which method to use, or if there is a single method most web developers use?

**Questions to Think About // TL;DR**

- What is the best method for uploading images that most of you use?
- Would you consider using mySQL 'blob' datatype?
- If uploading the image to a file directory is best, how would I display
  the images--using an array, placing the list of images in a DB, or something entirely different *(because I'm a noob and don't know any better)*

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: disk file is less ,expensive and it does not require database access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't use database storage for large images, just upload them and write the file path/name and details into a database.  Have a field in the database for Priority if you need to retrieve the images in a specific order

Just found [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) today, works great

Answer (score -1):

I use this on a project i'm working on and the way to go without having to write the files to disk is using a text column with the image as base64 string encoded data. The beauty of this is that you can output the file directly to browser via Data uri (info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).