# Error Update only Field type Attachment MS-Access C# WindowForm

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

It can update field type Text.

```
string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\test.accdb;";
        using (OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            MyConn.Open();
            var StrCmd = "UPDATE Table1 SET Field1 = @p2 WHERE ID = @p1";
            OleDbCommand oldcommand = new OleDbCommand(StrCmd, MyConn);
            byte[] pic = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\test.png");

            oldcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            oldcommand.CommandText = StrCmd;
            oldcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", "test");
            oldcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "1");
            try
            {
                oldcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

But It can not update field type Attachment.

Error  No value given for one or more required parameters.

```
string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\test.accdb;";
        using (OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            MyConn.Open();
            var StrCmd = "UPDATE Table1 SET Field2.Value = @p2 WHERE ID = @p1";
            OleDbCommand oldcommand = new OleDbCommand(StrCmd, MyConn);
            byte[] pic = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\test.png");

            oldcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            oldcommand.CommandText = StrCmd;
            oldcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", pic);
            oldcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "1");
            try
            {
                oldcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

[My Database MS-Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLCx6.jpg)
[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhC3w.jpg)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not quite clear to me what you are trying to do.
Are you trying to change the column type?

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821783.aspx) field introduced in the ACE Engine with MS Access 2007 is a [complex data type](http://bytecomb.com/microsoft-access-field-data-type-reference/) that actually contains multiple fields in each record (hidden in the Access GUI):

1. file name
2. file extension
3. binary content of file

Hence, you may not be able to run any queries (select with joins, update, or append) directly with it. In fact, you cannot run [DDL procedures](http://allenbrowne.com/func-DDL.html) with such a field type. You may only be able to use the Access GUI to manage the field.

Often a regular debate especially on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815626/to-do-or-not-to-do-store-images-in-a-database) involves storing media or other binary content (docs, pdfs, etc.) inside a database or on a file system. Portability is a huge advantage for former and performance for latter. Due to the limitation of the ACE attachment data type, consider storing path links in database as string that references externally stored files. Then your application can run any query needed.