# where to store pictures while paging in php. database or Folder?

Tags: php, mysql, image

Where can i store picture while paging. Whether it should be stored in folder or db. What to store in the db. entire images or only path. if path only how to get the path for a picture in a directory.  Please help me

---

**Exact Duplicate:** [User Images: Database or filesystem storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585224/user-images-database-vs-filesystem-storage)
**Exact Duplicate:** [Storing images in database: Yea or nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)
**Exact Duplicate:** [Should I store my images in the database or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713243/should-i-store-my-images-in-the-database-or-folders)
**Exact Duplicate:** [Would you store binary data in database or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662488/would-you-store-binary-data-in-database-or-in-file-system)
**Exact Duplicate:** [Store pictures as files or or the database for a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app)
**Exact Duplicate:** [Storing a small number of images: blob or fs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325126/storing-a-small-number-of-images-blob-or-fs)
**Exact Duplicate:** [store image in filesystem or database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766048/store-image-in-database-or-in-a-system-file)

Comment: This question has been asked many, many times.  Doing a search before asking your question is often prudent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably store the images in a folder and just have the database point to it. Your filesystem is setup to store files well and access them efficiently so just use that. If you have a content root directory hardcoded as a constant in your code you can just use that and build a path based on the path stored in the database.