# MySQL - storing images in a database?

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say each row of our table contains information about various vehicles for sale. And each user can store several images of each vehicle. 
What might be a good approach to storing these images?

**Duplicate:** [User Images: Database or filesystem storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585224/user-images-database-vs-filesystem-storage)
**Duplicate:** [Storing images in database: Yea or nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)
**Duplicate:** [Should I store my images in the database or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713243/should-i-store-my-images-in-the-database-or-folders)
**Duplicate:** [Would you store binary data in database or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662488/would-you-store-binary-data-in-database-or-in-file-system)
**Duplicate:** [Store pictures as files or or the database for a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app)
**Duplicate:** [Storing a small number of images: blob or fs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325126/storing-a-small-number-of-images-blob-or-fs)
**Duplicate:** [store image in filesystem or database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766048/store-image-in-database-or-in-a-system-file)

Comment: This question has been asked many many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like homework. You’d want a one-to-many relationship from the `vehicles` table to the `pictures` table. The `pictures` table would contain a BLOB column with the images. Or it could contain a VARCHAR column with the filenames of the images as stored on disk.

Comment: IMHO the database is the wrong place to store images. just store the location of the image.

Comment: I agree, most of the time. I think this is homework and the OP needs to be aware of the two common ways of doing this.

Comment: you can use a single folder, the database should know which files are owned by which user, so its your code who's decide what can be overwritten by a user and what can't.
you can store the images with the PK ID + filetype extension, or as a MD5 hash or ..... many many ways, but dont store them with the orginal filename. this makes far more problems (spaces in filename, specialchars.. aso.)

Comment: @DJDonaL3000: Most filesystems will slow down if you store too many images in a single folder. One way to deal with this is to use a hierarchical folder structure. For example, if your images are named 100.jpg, 101.jpg, 225.jpg, and so on, create a folder /images/100 and store images 100-199 there. Create a folder /images/200 etc. Another approach is to use [hash buckets](http://www.mondofacto.com/facts/dictionary?hash+bucket) where each bucket corresponds to one folder in the filesystem.

Comment: An alternate approach would be to use something like Amazon S3, where you can put an unlimited number of uniquely-named images in a single bucket and then refer to them by URL in your web page.

Answer (score 1):

i would prefer you should store pictures in some folders , so at the time of retrieving it will make easy. If you want to store in database you can use BLOB datatype.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of storing the image data directly in the database can become an issue, especially for large sites with a lot of traffic.

Usually I have a naming convention for storing the images on the server, and the file names are re-written from whatever the user uploads, but you can retain the original file name from the user if you prefer - just make sure to sanitize them.  The database only stores metadata for the images, so that requests for the image files can be handled directly by the webserver.