# Storing Images in DB is Good or Not?

Tags: iphone

What should I do? I have more than 1600 Images. Should I store them directly in the application or store them in a database. Right now I'm storing in Application and my application gets hanged so please Help

---

**Exact Duplicate:** [User Images: Database or filesystem storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585224/user-images-database-vs-filesystem-storage)
**Exact Duplicate:** [Storing images in database: Yea or nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)
**Exact Duplicate:** [Should I store my images in the database or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713243/should-i-store-my-images-in-the-database-or-folders)
**Exact Duplicate:** [Would you store binary data in database or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662488/would-you-store-binary-data-in-database-or-in-file-system)
**Exact Duplicate:** [Store pictures as files or or the database for a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app)
**Exact Duplicate:** [Storing a small number of images: blob or fs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325126/storing-a-small-number-of-images-blob-or-fs)
**Exact Duplicate:** [store image in filesystem or database?][7]

Comment: I wonder just how many times this question can get asked?

Answer (score 1):

As with most issues, it's not as simple as it sounds. There are cases where it would make sense to store the images in the database.

- You are storing images that are
  changing dynamically, say invoices
  and you wanted to get an invoice as
  it was on 1 Jan 2007?
- The government wants you to maintain
  6 years of history Images stored in
  the database do not require a
  different backup strategy. Images
  stored on filesystem do
- It is easier to control access to the
  images if they are in a database.
  Idle admins can access any folder on
  disk. It takes a really determined
  admin to go snooping in a database to
  extract the images

On the other hand there are problems associated

- Require additional code to extract
  and stream the images
- Latency may be slower than direct
  file access
- Heavier load on the web server

This answer is quoted from "[Conrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1349/conrad)"

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out previously, it depends.

One of the most common practices is to decide on the basis of the images' size.
For very small images, such as thumbnails, icons etc, you certainly store them in the DB, and you can store them as a field of an entity (say a contact).

For medium sized images, it still makes sense to store them in the DB. However, you have to decide by yourself what is a medium sized image (my threshold is 1 MByte), and you should store the image not as a field of an entity: you should create an image entity and a relation to the interested entity (say the contact).

Finally, very large images should not be stored in the DB. You store them on disk and store on the DB their pathnames. This is necessary owing to the different latency and access time of the hard disk versus the DB. Indeed, it is the DB fast access through indexes that allows you to store medium and small sized images in the DB, but huge images should be handled differently.