# Photo storage for web app

Tags: asp.net, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User images - database vs. filesystem storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585224/user-images-database-vs-filesystem-storage)

Hello ! Where should i store photos for a facebook-like app ? locally on the server in a folder or upload them to a database ? I am not intending to make this app commercial .

Comment: possible duplicate of [User images - database vs. filesystem storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585224/user-images-database-vs-filesystem-storage) **OR** [Store pictures as files or in the database for a web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store images in file system(folders) and store path in database.

**EDIT:**

Found an interesting article about How Facebook handle image storage:

[Facebook: Needle in a Haystack: Efficient Storage of Billions of Photos](http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/2008/06/30/FacebookNeedleInAHaystackEfficientStorageOfBillionsOfPhotos.aspx)

**Some facts from above article:**

- Photo facts:

  - 6.5B photos in total

    - 4 to 5 sizes of each picture is materialized (30B files)
    - 475k images/second

      - Mostly served via CDN (Akamai & Limelight)
      - 200k profile photos/second
    - 100m uploads/week
  - Stored on [netapp filers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetApp_filer)

Comment: :) Indeed recommended read. I guess this is the right URL http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919&comments I suggest to take small steps, start conventional, and when you find your site is flooded with uploads and requests beyond the limits -- go for something like this.

Comment: The James Hamilton post is very interesting, and it's two years old! I guess they multiplied all this by a big number now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer files to be stored in file-system and data to be stored in database. So, what I will do is I will upload the file and save it in file system.. in a directory. Say, /home/username/appfiles/ and in data base I will have a reference to it. Say, under column image_location: /home/username/appfiles/image_file_name.

What I will also do is I will rename the file by appending a timestamp to make sure two files with same name does not get over-written.

Comment: imo it's more practical to store the path like /appfiles/image_file_name and store the prefix somewhere else, so when you move the files for some reason, you can just change the prefix instead of the whole database.

Comment: right. That was just a bonus suggestion. I keep file_storage_directory as a configurable propery. And then I store the file-path relative to it, in DB. When I need to pull out the file, I just concat these two. In case I have moved my files to somewhere else, I will just update config settings. done.